# Variable not in variable explorer in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter

I may be a noob in Python, but I haven't been having a lot of fun with its variable inspectors compared to programming languages like R.

For one thing, I find it almost impossible to inspect the elements within a dict or array objects through the variable inspector (I can't click the name of the object and scroll through the columns and rows).

Not to mention, there are some objects that outright don't show. For example, I've been working quite awhile with Music21 libraries, and a lot of objects created end up being some kind of class.

Example:

```
n1 = note.Note('C4')
n1
>>> <music21.note.Note C>
```

However, whenever I want to inspect further the details of those class, I find it almost impossible because the object 'n1' does not show up on the variable inspector.

Is there a good place I can look at or is there a good way to fix these?

Comment: Python is a general purpose programming language, so the tooling is generally not the same as R. Usually, you want to *read the relevant documentation*. That being said, Python objects are highly introspectable. And most IDEs will support tab-completion, etc. There is also the buit-in `help` function when you are working in a REPL. Anyway, I don't think Jupyter notebooks have anything like a "variable explorer" like in RStudio.

Comment: " and a lot of objects created end up being some kind of class." all objects, **everything**, is an instance of a class in Python.